# Git synchronize all remote branches to local

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I have a script for update all my local repositories.
I'm using a windows computer, and I'm using a .bat script for automatically update all my local repositories.

My folder structure is

```
xx/update.bat

xx/project1/ ..
xx/project2/ ..
etc..
etc..
```

my bat script now is:

```
 @echo off
 for /D %%G in ("*") do (echo %%G)  && (cd %%G) && (git fetch --all) && (git pull --all) && (cd ..)
```

but this script will update only the tracked branches, if a new branch is added in remote it will not added automatically to my local repository.

I need help to enhance this script for execute "git branch --track" for all branches in all repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git maintains a local cache of what branches exist on the remote server. This cache tends to become outdated because it isn't refreshed automatically.

To refresh this local cache, use this command:

```
git remote update origin --prune
```

In git cheatsheets you may see this command described as "*Update local list of remote branches*".